# Line on dataZoom is different from line chart

Tags: javascript, echarts

[image: image of a line chart]

I use echarts with line style to draw the histogram, but with the discontinuous time periods the main graph is showing properly but on dataZoom's chart appear different line, I understand it's because the plot on dataZoom is drawing an area chart

Is there a way to draw a line chart on dataZoom?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do this in ECharts:

```js
dataZoom: [{
    type: 'inside',
    start: 50,
    end: 100,
    xAxisIndex: [0],
    filterMode: 'empty'
}, {
    type: 'slider',
    start: 50,
    end: 100,
    xAxisIndex: [0],
    filterMode: 'empty',
    bottom: 0,
    height: 20,
    handleIcon: 'M10.7,11.9H9.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7V23h6.6V24.4z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.4h6.6V19.6z',
    handleSize: '120%',
    handleStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        shadowBlur: 3,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
        shadowOffsetX: 2,
        shadowOffsetY: 2
    }
}],
```